# Wordpress pagination showing same content on page 2

Tags: wordpress, loops, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I can’t link to the site I’m working on because it’s running locally right now. I’m trying to use pagination on the home page but what happens is that it’s displaying a link for Page 2 and Page 3 but it’s not showing any different content when I click the links.

I’m using the bootstrap framework (no plugin). I want to try pagination without using a plugin.

I have a query running on the home page that pulls in the latest 3 posts into the first 3 columns (1,2,3).

I have an additional query running on the home page that pulls in the next 3 posts into 3 columns beneath the first 3 (4,5,6).

When the pagination displays, I click on the numbers and the url changes in the address bar but the content remains the same. Is there a way I can use pagination to continue to display 3 columns on top and 3 columns on bottom?

Please help, thanks!

In my functions.php I have:

```
function bootstrap_pagination($pages = '', $range = 2) {
$showitems = ($range * 2)+1;
global $paged;
if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

if($pages == '') {
    global $wp_query;
$pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
if(!$pages) {
    $pages = 1;
}
}

if(1 != $pages) {
echo "<div class='pagination pagination-centered'><ul>";
if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<li><a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo;</a></li>";
if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<li><a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo;</a></li>";

for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems )) {
echo ($paged == $i)? "<li class='active'><span class='current'>".$i."</span></li>":"<li><a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class='inactive' >".$i."</a></li>";
}
}

if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<li><a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>&rsaquo;</a></li>";
if ($paged < $pages-1 && $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<li><a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>&raquo;</a></li>";
echo "</ul></div>\n";
}
}
```

Query 1 looks like this:

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="span4">            
                <div class="our-work-thumbs">
                <?php 
                // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail();
                } 
                ?>          
                <h4><?php the_title(); ?> - <span><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>">view project</a></span></h4>              
                </div> 
                </div>            

<?php $count1++; } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>  
</div>      
<!------------ FIRST ROW ---------------->
```

Query 2 looks like this:

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="span4">            
                <div class="our-work-thumbs">
                <?php 
                // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail();
                } 
                ?>          
                <h4><?php the_title(); ?> - <span><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>">view project</a></span></h4>              
                </div> 
                </div>            

<?php $count2++; } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>    
<?php endif; ?>  
<!------------ SECOND ROW ---------------->
```

Comment: Research in [wordpress.se], this has already been answered over there in almost every variation of the problem.